# "New User" but with 12k+ Reputation in Late Answers

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, late-answers

While checking in the **Late Answers**, I happened to encounter an answer from a 12k user, but is considered a new user. Is this a bug of some sort?

Here's an image for visuals:

[image: Image of the Issue]

I'll add the link and/or the unedited image if needed.

Comment: Is it an audit? Looks like one. Does that answer actually exist on the question? Probably not.

Comment: @Bugs The link is working, and the answer is there

Comment: This kind of question should have gone in low quality ? Seems like a link only answer.

Comment: I just reviewed it, it is an audit, as @Bugs said.

Comment: There are often obvious signs to an audit. This is clearly not a _new user_. That being said you could have flagged as NAA and you would have passed because the answer has in fact been deleted. Ironically had you flagged as NAA on the actual answer (not in a review and if it existed) the flag would probably have been declined. All very confusing really and a bit misleading.